# Obtaining Australian visa to re-enter the country on a British passport?

Tags: visas, australia, uk-citizens

I am a UK citizen living in Australia and hold a UK passport.  How do I obtain an Australian visa to re-enter the country when I leave for a holiday?

Comment: what visa are you on in Australia? Perm residence, working holiday or other?

Comment: What do you need the visa for, to travel, visit, live, work, study ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are a permanent resident of Australia, you can apply for a [Resident Return visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/155-157.aspx) which allows you to return to Australia with your existing status.

> The Resident Return visa (subclasses 155 and 157) is for current or former Australian permanent residents and former Australian citizens who want to travel overseas and return to Australia as permanent residents.
>
> The Resident Return visa will let you keep or regain your status as an Australian permanent resident.
>
> Only Australian citizens have an automatic right of entry to Australia. All non-citizens need a visa that allows them to enter and remain in Australia.

If you are not a permanent resident (for example, if you have a temporary work visa), then you wil need to check the conditions on your visa to see whether it allows multiple entry within a time period that covers your intended holiday.